# CSS - select th tags only within the tbody of a table

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to use a css selector to get only the th tags with the tbody.  There are also th tags in the thead section, which I don't want included by the selector.  Here's the markup I'm working with.  Is there a selector to accomplish this?

```
<table class="bgtable">
<thead><tr><td width="40%">&nbsp;</td>
<th class="tdplain">Grade 4</th>
<th class="tdplain">Grade 8</th>
<th class="tdplain">Grade 12</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr><th class="tdplain">Civics (2010)</th>
<td class="tdplain">769K</td>
<td class="tdplain">577K</td>
<td class="tdplain">1179K</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
.bgtable tbody th {
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
table.bgtable tbody th {
 /* CSS rules here */
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's actually true. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.5 <- row groups contain `TRs`. `TRs` contain `TH|TD`. Can you link the spec that says you can't have a `TH` in `TBODY`?

Comment: I 2nd Joel's comment. I can't find any spec that says you can't have a `TH` in a `TBODY`.

Comment: The W3C Validator's been a little slow this morning. I finally got it to load and ran a test - you guys are right!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the downvotes? My answer is effectively the same as the accepted one. I don't mind being downvoted but comments are appreciated.

Comment: +1: It is correct, but don't use the element type selector if you can help it, *i.e.*, don't use `table.bgtable` if `.bgtable` works.

Answer (score 2):

```
tbody>tr>th {color:red;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the previous are all valid, one can still be more precise (the css-selecting being not so performant).

```
table.bgtable > tbody > th {
color:red;
}
```

if you got more than one table, which doesn't belong to the class, you don't want to include it to your selection that's why "table.bgtable".

kwoning to you can embeded th with other tag withitn the tbody you would be sure to find them  otherwise like that: `table.bgtable > tbody th`